# in the callhistory.storedata database, table - zcallrecord, what are the values for zdisconnected_cause and what do they mean?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am looking on an ios device.  The field zdisconnected_cause is an integer field, but I can't find an explanation of what the values of the field mean, or what blanks mean.  Anyone know where a table structure and definitions are located for apple database? Is there a website? A book?

Answer (score 0):

Was in a similar boat. That's "private API" and not documented, so our best approach is to check for regularities in the values and make informed guesses.

I know it's not much of a help, but I personally decided to ignore this field and a couple of others because I could make neither heads not tails from it.